# 400 error on send anti forgery token using axios.post

Tags: .net, vue.js, .net-core, antiforgerytoken

I got `ApiController`, with atribute  `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]`

I added Antiforgery for my razor form:

```
                <form 
                    action="" 
                    class="default-form"

                >
                    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
```

But I use Vue.js in combination with Axios to send my form data.

```
let __RequestVerificationToken = form.querySelector('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]');
```

and trying to send it using Axios

```
            axios.post(url, data, {
            headers: {
              'RequestVerificationToken': __RequestVerificationToken
            }})
```

Also, Send `__RequestVerificationToken` as part of the data on post request.
Controller work's perfect without the attribute.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was here

```
        headers: {
          RequestVerificationToken: __RequestVerificationToken.value
        }})
```

The naming of the header - shouldn't be a text. And I forget about get the value from the variable.